# Are Confidential Transactions in Monero perfectly binding or hiding?

Tags: security, ringct, privacy, cryptography, confidential-transactions

Bitcoin contributor Pieter Wuille recently [commented on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/7d5zbc/finally_real_privacy_for_bitcoin_transactions/dpvbocv/?context=3):

> Bulletproofs and the Pedersen commitments they operate on are
>   perfectly hiding, but not perfectly binding. This roughly means that
>   if they're adopted inside Bitcoin, and elliptic curve crypto is
>   (completely) broken, new money can be printed. On the flip side, it
>   does mean that the privacy of anyone who used CT in the past is
>   unaffected. Alternative formulations of CT exist for which this is the
>   other way around (perfectly binding but not perfectly hiding), where
>   money can never be printed (even if the cryptography is broken), but
>   privacy can be retroactively lost. There is currently a discussion on
>   the mailinglist which of these is the better tradeoff (it is
>   mathematically impossible to have both perfect hiding and binding).

Which design did Monero choose to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perfectly hiding. I don't think perfectly binding even existed at the time RCT was developed (not sure, though).

As to what should be chosen, think about this:

> We can always replace lost money, but we can't ever replace lost privacy.

Comment: just for clarification blinding == hiding, not binding right?

Comment: yup; edited to hiding